# Algorithm for Pointillize effect like Photoshop

Tags: image-processing, glsl, photoshop

I tried like this:

```
float rand(vec2 co) {
    return fract(sin(dot(co, vec2(12.9898, 78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;
    
    
    float iDotSize = 0.01;       // Normalized dot size (0 to 1)
    float iMaxDotDistance = iDotSize * 2.0;

    
    // Calculate the dot position by adding a random offset
    float dotOffset = (rand(uv) * 2.0 - 1.0) * iMaxDotDistance;
    vec2 dotPosition = uv + dotOffset;

    // Calculate the dot size based on the desired radius
    float dotSize = iDotSize * iResolution.x;

    // Sample the color from the input image at the dot position
    vec3 dotColor = texture(iChannel0, dotPosition).rgb;

    // Render the dot
    if (distance(uv, dotPosition) < dotSize) {
        fragColor = vec4(dotColor, 1.0);
    } else {
        // Render the background
        fragColor = texture(iChannel0, uv);
        fragColor = vec4(0.0);
    }
    
    //fragColor = vec4(0.0);
    
    // Output to screen
    //fragColor = texture(iChannel0, circleCenter);
}
```

But this not what I am expecting. I expect the effect like photoshop.
What is the algorithm for that? I want to implement in GLSL. Reference Image:

[image]

My output: [image]

Comment: _"But this not what I am expecting"_ - **Show us your actual input and actual output**

Comment: I have added my output

Comment: Looks like you need to leave out 95% of the dots and make the remaining ones x4 times larger.